# Removing stopwords from tweets Python

Tags: python, loops, nltk, tweets, stop-words

I am trying to remove stopwords from tweets that I have imported from Twitter. After removing the stopwords, the list of strings will be placed in a new column in the same row. I can easily accomplish this one row at a time however when attempting to loop the method over the whole Data Frame does not seem to succeed.

How do would I do this?

Snippet of my data:

```
tweets['text'][0:5]
Out[21]: 
0    Why #litecoin will go over 50 USD soon ? So ma...
1    get 20 free #bitcoin spins at...
2    Are you Bullish or Bearish on #BMW? Start #Tra...
3    Are you Bullish or Bearish on the S&amp;P 500?...
4    TIL that there is a DAO ExtraBalance Refund. M...
```

The following works in a single row scenario:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
tweets['text-filtered'] = ""

word_tokens = word_tokenize(tweets['text'][1])
filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words] 
tweets['text-filtered'][1] = filtered_sentence

tweets['text-filtered'][1]
Out[22]: 
['get',
 '20',
 'free',
 '#',
 'bitcoin',
 'spins',
 'withdraw',
 'free',
 '#',
 'btc',
 '#',
 'freespins',
 '#',
 'nodeposit',
 '#',
 'casino',
 '#',
 '...',
 ':']
```

My attempt at a loop does not succeed:

```
for i in tweets:
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(tweets.get(tweets['text'][i], False))
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words] 
    tweets['text-filtered'][i] = filtered_sentence
```

A snippet of the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-6d7dace7a2d0>", line 2, in <module>
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(tweets.get(tweets['text'][i], False))

...

KeyError: 'id'
```

Based off @Prune's reply, I have managed to correct my mistakes. Here is a potential solution:

```
count = 0    
for i in tweets['text']:
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(i)
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words]
    tweets['text-filtered'][count] = filtered_sentence
    count += 1
```

My previous attempt was looping through the columns of the Data Frame, tweets. The first column in tweets was "id".

```
tweets.columns
Out[30]: 
Index(['id', 'user_bg_color', 'created', 'geo', 'user_created', 'text',
       'polarity', 'user_followers', 'user_location', 'retweet_count',
       'id_str', 'user_name', 'subjectivity', 'coordinates',
       'user_description', 'text-filtered'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confused about list indexing:

```
for i in tweets:
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(tweets.get(tweets['text'][i], False))
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words] 
    tweets['text-filtered'][i] = filtered_sentence
```

Note that `tweets` is a dictionary; `tweets['text']`list of strings.  Thus, `for i in tweets` returns all of the keys in `tweets`: the dictionary keys in arbitrary order.  It appears that "id" is the first one returned.  When you try to assign `tweets['text-filtered']['id'] = filtered_sentence`, there just is no such element.

Try coding more gently: start at the inside, code a few lines at a time, and work your way up to more complex control structures.  Debug each addition before you go on.  Here, you seem to have lost your sense of what is a numeric index, what is a list, and what is a dictionary.

Since you haven't done any visible debugging, or provided the context, I can't fix the whole program for you -- but this should get you started.

Comment: My confusion between indices, lists and dictionary was the problem! I've updated my answer based on what you suggested